# pick two images separately in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm making and android app where I need two upload images and save them to server. 
[image]

When I select it from the first button, it is appeared in the second but I need two different images.

```
photoUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImage();
            }
        });

        photoUpload2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void chooseImage() {
        Intent openGalleryIntent = new Intent();
        openGalleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        openGalleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(openGalleryIntent, "Select Picture"), GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this because you are setting selected image to imageview 1  and 2. to solve this you can use different request codes or use Boolean variable to differentiate the uploading of image 1 and 2

Define two Boolean variable to differentiate the uploading of image 1 and 2

```
Boolean first = false, second = false;


      @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                first = true;
                chooseImage();
            }
        });

        photoUpload2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            second = true;
                chooseImage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void chooseImage() {
        Intent openGalleryIntent = new Intent();
        openGalleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        openGalleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(openGalleryIntent, "Select Picture"), GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                if(first)
                {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    first = false;
                }else if(second)
                {
                 imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 second = false;
                 }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

You can use library to select multiple images from Gallery. There are many libraries that are available, one such is https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker

Hope this will help you!
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You are setting same image to both ImageViews.

Change Your Code to

```
 photoUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chooseImage(GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE_1);
        }
    });

    photoUpload2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chooseImage(GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE_2);
        }
    });
}

private void chooseImage(int requestCode) {
    Intent openGalleryIntent = new Intent();
    openGalleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    openGalleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(openGalleryIntent, "Select Picture"), requestCode);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE_1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();


        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE_2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set same bitmap in both imageView
You should try bellow code

```
boolean isFromFirstBtn;

photoUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isFromFirstBtn = true;
            chooseImage();
        }
    });

    photoUpload2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isFromFirstBtn = false;
            chooseImage();
        }
    });
}

private void chooseImage() {
    Intent openGalleryIntent = new Intent();
    openGalleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    openGalleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(openGalleryIntent, "Select Picture"), GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            if(isFromFirstBtn){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }else{
                imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```